# Are there D&D-5e resources that provide tips and methods for puzzle building?

Tags: dnd-5e, puzzle

I am running a play by post campaign, and will soon run a typical D&D campaign with a few players. I wish to de-emphasize combat to favor role-playing and the use of strategy, partly because of the play by post format where combat takes longer.

Has Wizards of the Coast published resources about how to build puzzles, enigmas, mysteries, and other types of challenges that would require figuring things out rather than the use of combat?

Comment: Of course! When you have some time, the [help] has a bunch of [articles about asking questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/asking) that give some more concrete and detailed guidance on writing questions for the site. We aren’t a traditional discussion forum, so we do have some expectations you might not see on discussion forum type sites, but those help center articles should give you a good idea about how things work here.

Answer (score 7):

#### Chapter 4 of *Tasha’a Cauldron of Everything* has a section on puzzles.

*Tasha’s Cauldron* has a helpful section on puzzles, giving some generic conceptual guidance and inspiration for creating your own, as well as several concrete examples of puzzles you can include in your game.

Overall, *Tasha’s Cauldron* was a helpful book. It includes lots of additional character options, and some helpful worldbuilding tools for DMs.